# How to check for the existence of an object's property inside an "if" condition statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a list of objects of type `ROUTE`.

Each `ROUTE` object contains string properties, but some objects do not contain the  `EXITSIGNAL` property (doesn't exist not null)

some of code :

```
List<ROUTE> SelectedRoutes = new List<ROUTE>();
foreach (var route in XmlData.ROUTES)
{
   if (sig.SignalID.Equals(route.ENTRANCESIGNAL) &&
       sig.SignalDIRECTION.Equals(route.DIRECTION) &&                     
       "Condition on EXITSIGNAL property")
   {
       SelectedRoutes.Add(route);
   }
}
```

How to add a third condition that allows me to choose only objects that contain this property "EXITSIGNAL"

Comment: `XmlData.ROUTES.Where(x => x?.EXITSIGNAL != null)`

Comment: _"but some objects do not contain the  EXITSIGNAL"_ What's the type of these objects? Are you still talking about `ROUTE` objects? Because one type would always have the same properties.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Sounds like they're xml nodes.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The OP said _"doesn't exist, not null"_ though.

Comment: If your objects are strictly typed, then all of them share similar properties. Please clarify more on `ROUTE` type and how the objects of this type can have different numbers of properties.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Most of these objects (of type ROUTE) have the same properties except some where the property "EXITSIGNAL" is missing

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I retrieved my list "ROUTES" from a deserialization of an xml file

Comment: @Amibluesky If you deserialized the XML file into a list of objects of a specific type (`ROUTE` in this case), then **all the objects share the same properties**; that's by default. Whether they have a value or NULL is a different story. Note that if the `EXITSIGNAL` node is missing from the XML file, it doesn't mean that it'll be missing as a property of the object. No, the property is always there; it'll just be null.

Comment: @Amibluesky It would be helpful if you could show the object definition of `ROUTE`. Also, is there any inheritance involved? Are there child classes of `ROUTE`? Is it a child class of something else?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would test if the object is of a class that contains the property. i.e. `if (route is ROUTECLASS_WITH_EXITSIGNAL)` ...
And if you have several classes that have the property make them derived from a common class that contains EXITSIGNAL and is derived from ROUTE then test if `is EXITSIG_CLASSTYPE`.

Based on the code you provided you could get the Type info for the ROUTE object and see if it supports the EXITSIGNAL property, assuming all the EXITSIGNAL properties are similar in type.

```
List<ROUTE> SelectedRoutes = new List<ROUTE>();
foreach (var route in XmlData.ROUTES)
{
   bool bHasExitSig = false;
   if (route.GetType().GetProperty("EXITSIGNAL", typeof(string)) != null)
   {
       bHasExitSig = true;
   }

   if (sig.SignalID.Equals(route.ENTRANCESIGNAL) &&
       sig.SignalDIRECTION.Equals(route.DIRECTION) &&                     
       bHasExitSig)
   {
       SelectedRoutes.Add(route);
   }
}
```